# Alarms that trigger by time of day in C

Tags: c, timer, signals

I would like to have an alarm/timer in C that triggers a signal at a certain time of day, regardless of when the program starts. For example, I could start the program at 10:00, and it generates a signal at 00:00 and then at 00:00 every subsequent day. Or I could start it at 07:00 and it still generates a signal at 00:00. Is there an easy way to achieve this functionality?

I can use forking or threads, but I'm wondering if thats necessary. Thanks.

Comment: any reason you have to have your app do this? why not just schedule a job with the host OS's own scheduler, e.g. `cron` on unix?

Comment: You can use the time library. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)

Comment: This should give you a start: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

Comment: Please don't! As @MarcB already stated, for things like this `cron` or `acron` (used by most Linux distributions instead of `cron`) exist. They provide flexible configuration and a standard interface. There are also some GUI-tools available to manage the tables. AFAIK, Windows also provides a time-scheduling service.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. I already started looking at doing it using cron. I was trying to self contain this as much as possibly because the machines running the code are radar site computers that are not accessible. If they go down for whatever reason, it just complicates restarting things again. Its not that bad though. I can just add more to the start up scripts.

Comment: ok, but if you use the built-in system scheduler, then the jobs are there until the system completely dies (e.g. wipe/reinstall). cron's relatively simplistic, but the windows scheduler has all kinds of options on what to do if the scheduled time is missed.